Understanding CPU Load on Small MCUs / How Fast Is Too Fast for SysTick?
To set the scene, if I configure the SysTick timer on my LPC824 (Arm Cortex M0+) to increment a volatile uint32_t counter every 10ms (SysTick->LOAD = 12MHz / 10 - 1) then it gets called at a rate of 10Hz as you'd expect...
If the system clock is 12MHz, and we assume that calling the SysTick_Handler interrupt and incrementing the volatile uint32_t has a "cost" of 20 instructions (this is a rough guess at best), it implies we could under "ideal" conditions call the SysTick_Handler at 600KHz.
But obviously we need some capacity for our code to actually do something useful in between counting really fast. Assuming the rough "cost" above, if we set the timer to interrupt at a rate of 300KHz it should leave about 50% of the cycles free to execute other code if my thought process is correct.
And so to the underlying for my question: On a low-end MCU such as the LPC824/CortexM0+, what is the most effective way to profile code and determine where processor time is being spent?
(I am aware of SWO but I don't believe this is available until the Cortex M3/M4 range).
EDIT: Made corrections to the "workings" as per @busybee comment.

You would be better to use one of the timers on the LPC824 rather than the sysTick interrupt. Then there would be no overhead, you just read the timer value when you want to know the "time". Pretty simple for small time intervals, but if there is the possibility that the timer might wrap around multiple times during your test, you'd need something better. But having to run some code for every single tick is crazy.

you can also use the systick timer in that way, it is a freerunning timer so you can just sample it twice and see how long something takes.   remember it is 24 bit so mask the subtraction with 0x00FFFFFF.

HOW You sample the time is as important as the time, if you have a function in the high level language sample time through some library or even if it is a simple function, and then run some function you want to time and then call a function to read the timer, you may end up with a lot of error.   depending on the mcu you may have a flash cache you cannot turn off and/or the first pass, second pass and perhaps further may have different execution times (WILL on a certain very popular brand) so you can do the loop 1000 times thing and measure that way.

20 instructions is definitely not assumed to be 20 clocks, assume the flash is half the rate and so that is 40 clock cycles to do the fetches, any of these instructions being memory cycles or peripheral (any loads and stores) are going to take some number of clocks.   the interrupt is going to do many clock cycles to save state to the stack and restore state on the other end so another dozen or two clock cycles.

alignment and fetching as well as the flash caching can and will have an effect on profiling on these mcus.

another approach is to use a gpio pin and a scope to profile.  it has similar issues to the accuracy of time measurment as any other sometimes it is easier than a timer, esp for example if you do not have a easy way for the code under test to output its timing results.

Your powers of tens seem to be off seriously. -- 1) You start with SysTick->LOAD = 12MHz / 10 - 1; that lets it tick with 10 Hz in my understanding, but you claim 100 Hz. You are off by a factor of 10. -- 2) Then you estimate a maximum tick rate of 600 kHz, but claim that an interrupt rate of 300 Hz will take about 50% of available cycles. Here you are off by a factor of 1 k = 1000. -- Please [edit] your question to clarify.

To avoid complex calculations with flash access timing, processor pipelines, disassembly interpretation, and researching processor cycles for each instructions, I would simply add port pin toggles to the ticker's interrupt service routine. The main thread would toggle another port pin. With some oscilloscope or logic analyzer measurements I'll get at least good values for my future development.

Using a port to toggle on oscilloscope sounds a good plan, I'll give that a go!
